# Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin

Tags: android-studio

when i upgrade AndroidStudio 2.1 to 2.2 and gradle 2.14 to 2.2, there has a gradle compiled error:

> ```
> Error:Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin
> ```

Comment: What was the reason that it provided for not being able to initialize the class?

Comment: Have you fix it. Getting same issue after update

Answer (score 2):

If there are plugins specified in the project's gradle build files, check that they have been upgraded. I fixed this problem by upgrading `com.github.hierynomus.license` to the latest version.

Comment: May I ask how to "check my plugin"?

Comment: sorry I dont install this plugin!

Comment: @songzhw The plugins, at least in my project, are specified in the build.gradle in the root of the project.

Comment: Thanks for your replying. Yeah, but we normally just use "apply plugin 'nexus'", for example. We do not specific the version. It's not like "apply plugin 'nexus 1.1.0' ". May I ask how to check if the plugins have been upgraded or not?